# Different values of Initial weight of linear regression is converging to different minimized cost value

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I have implemented a univariate linear regression in python. The code is given below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,2,4,3,5,7,9,11])
y = np.array([3,5,9,7,11,15,19,23])

def hypothesis(w0,w1,x):
  return w0 + w1*x

def cost_cal(y,w0,w1,x,m):
  diff = hypothesis(w0,w1,x)-y
  diff_sqr = np.square(diff)
  total_cost = np.sum(diff)
  total_cost_sqr = (1/(2*m)) * np.sum(diff_sqr)
  return total_cost, total_cost_sqr

def gradient_descent(w0,w1,alpha,x,m,y):
  cost, cost_sqr = cost_cal(y,w0,w1,x,m)
  temp0 = (alpha/m) * cost
  temp1 = (alpha/m) * np.sum(cost*x)
  w0 = w0 - temp0
  w1 = w1 - temp1
  return w0,w1
```

These are my hypothesis, cost, and gradient_descent functions implemented in python. When I use the initial weight `w0 = 0` and `w1 = 0`, my minimized cost is `0.12589726000013188`. But, if I initialize the `w0 = -1` and `w1 = -2`, the minimized cost is `0.5035890400005265`. What is the reason behind the different minimum costs using different initial weight values? As the error function MSE, is a convex function, shouldn't it reach the global minimum? Am I doing something wrong?

```
w0=0
w1=0
alpha =0.0001
m = 8
z = 5000
c = np.zeros(z)
cs = np.zeros(z)
w0_arr=np.zeros(z)
w1_arr=np.zeros(z)
index = np.zeros(z)
i = 0

while (i<z):
  index[i] = i
  c[i],cs[i] = cost_cal(y,w0,w1,x,m)
  #print(i, c[i], cs[i])
  w0, w1 = gradient_descent(w0,w1,alpha,x,m,y)
  w0_arr[i],w1_arr[i] = w0,w1
  i=i+1

inc = np.argmin(cs)
print(inc)
print(cs[inc])
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer might vary based on your initial vector u choose in weight space. Apart from fact that the cost function is convex the curve has many critical points so it completely depends on the initial point or weights where we end up whether in local or global minima.

image link
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ltxplazySpc/XQG4aprY2iI/AAAAAAAABVo/xAqLIln9OWkig5rq4AU2sBFuPBuxW5CFQCLcBGAs/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/local_vs_global_minima.PNG

as per the image in the given link if u start from an initial point which is at the left corner we end up landing in global minima if we start from the right end we end up landing in local minima. Cost may vary by a huge difference but in most cases, the difference is not very large in case of local or global minima so if the cost is varying by big difference u need to cross-check once. Picking initial weights randomly is a good practice they should not be set manually.

in gradient_descent function, temp0 is assigned an array instead of the value, the sum of that array must be done before adding.